# Spinner load failed on IIS ASP NET Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, iis

I have a problem with the display of a loading gif.
It works fine under visual 2017 and IIS Express, but after posting to a target server and IIS, the GIF no longer loads. It is however present in the wwwroot / images

[image: Spinner]

[image: code]

I have tried several syntaxes for the GIF path, but nothing helps.

```
var spiner = "<img src=\"/images/ajax-loader.gif\" alt=\"Loading\" style=\"height: 40px; width: 40px\"/>"

var spiner = "<img src=\"~/images/ajax-loader.gif\" alt=\"Loading\" style=\"height: 40px; width: 40px\"/>"

var spiner = "<img src=\"../images/ajax-loader.gif\" alt=\"Loading\" style=\"height: 40px; width: 40px\"/>"
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Did you get any error messages? You can use F12 developer tools to check whether there are related error messages in the console.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the GIF does not have time to load to display.
I changed my code like this, with 5s display, and it displays correctly. Now the only concern is that it delays the refresh of my page. I have to find something else.

[image]